# Not able to Open Downloaded PDF file in Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

this is my code to take PDF files.when i am trying to open my downloaded PDF file in chrome,i am getting a error dialog with a message "Failed to load PDF document."

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
{
    var contentList = db.Output.Where(q => q.QID == id && q.FileName.Equals(FileName)).OrderBy(q => q.AQID).Select(q => q.TextValue).ToList();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < contentList.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}", contentList[i]);
        //  Response.WriteFile();
    }
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FileName + "\"");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: You lost some of the file so the size down loaded isn't matching the original file size of the download is gzip and you need to unzip the file.  The PDF is binary and you shouldn't be using StringBuilder on Binary data.

Comment: okay..then can u plz give me specific solution for this..i have tried but couldn't get the solution.

Comment: i don't have any idea that what can we use instead of StringBuilder.can u plz suggest the code.@jdweng

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: thanks @jdweng..i checked the link,but in my code i am trying to download file from my system location,and it is getting downloaded,but i am trying to open my downloaded file,i am getting one Message "Failed to load PDF document "

Comment: It is not getting completely downloaded.  The number of bytes is not matching the original file size.  Usually this indicates the file was binary and using an ascii method to download file which will change the bytes.  Sometimes it indicates the file was gzip and the code is not un zip the file.

Comment: okay @jdweng..any solution for this?

Comment: Yes.  Do not use String Builder on binary data.  I do not know where you get the code you posted.  That is why I provided a line to the download file method.  There a lots of methods to properly download binary files.  The code you posted is not one of them.

Comment: Actually the code i have posted is downloading the file but not loading when trying to open it.and in this code,i am supposed to make changes,to make it work.

Comment: Look at the number of bytes of file that you downloaded it is not the same size as the original file.

Comment: file size is same.

Comment: How are you determining the number of bytes?  Windows explorer doesn't show an exact byte count it truncates the number of bytes.

Comment: the folder from where i am downloading the file,and the folder where my downloaded file is getting saved,in both the folders i am comaparing the size of the file.

Comment: Did you compare with Beyond Compare?  Can you open by double clicking on file in windows explorer?

Comment: no i can't open the file..getting a alert that "could not open the file,bcoz either its not supported or has been damaged"

Comment: That is what I'm saying.  The file size is not really the same and comparing with Beyond Compare may give clue to where the changes are being made.  For example when download in ascii the return character may get change from a return to a return and linefeed.  If the error is not all the bytes are getting downloaded then the files will be the same at the beginning and different at the end.

Comment: thanks for your effort @jdweng